# Copy Lists method doesn't work

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to make a copy lists method as this one  Collections.copy(,);

I want to make it my self so I made this one

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class NewMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a1={"asdasd","sadasd","asdasd"};

        List<String> l1= Arrays.asList(a1);

        String[] a2=new  String[3];
        List<String> l2= Arrays.asList(a2);
        copy(l1,l2);
    }

    public static void copy(List<String> copy_from,List<String> copy_to){

        for(int i=0;i<=copy_from.size();i++){
            System.out.print(  copy_from.containsAll(copy_to));
        }
    }

}
```

I know the problem from  containsAll method , but what should I use ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What does the loop do? It appears to just perform the same operation over and over. More importantly, you're not actually calling any methods that modify the new, empty list.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just clear the first list and add everything from the second list to the first?

Comment: copy_from.containsAll(copy_to) checks that copy_from contains all elements in copy_to which is false since copy_to contains 4 nulls.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<=copy_from.size();i++){
    System.out.print(  copy_from.containsAll(copy_to));
}
```

Does nothing besides a `sysout` statement.

You want something along the lines of:

```
public static void copy(List<String> copy_from,List<String> copy_to){
    if (copy_from.size() > copy_to.size())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Source does not fit in dest");
    } else {
        for(String toCopy : copy_from) {
            copy_to.add(toCopy);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a for each loop that loops over every element in your copy_from list and adds it to your copy_to list.

Comment: This won't perform the same operation as `Collections.copy`. From the javadoc: "Copies all of the elements from one list into another. After the operation, the index of each copied element in the destination list will be identical to its index in the source list. **The destination list must be at least as long as the source list. If it is longer, the remaining elements in the destination list are unaffected**."

Comment: Thank you all. I want as  you wrote exactly 

each loop it the easiest way , but I got  exception  problem 

If I tried  your solution 
--------------------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
 at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
 at tst.Tst.copy(Tst.java:38)
 at tst.Tst.main(Tst.java:28)
Java Result: 1

What should I do ?

Comment: That is an issue with the way you create your arraylist. That exception indicates you are using an immutable list.

Answer (score 0):

This should do assuming copy_from and copy_to can grow as we add elements.

```
public static void copy(List<String> copy_from,List<String> copy_to) throws Exception {
        //handle exception according to your wish
        if (copy_from !=null && copy_to == null) {
             throw new Exception("Source is not empty by Destination is null");
        }
        for(String string : copy_from){
           copy_to.add(string);
        }
  }
```

Comment: What's the problem with source == null? It should be a legal operation to copy nothing from nothing and it should do it without the check.

Comment: I already mentioned that was optional. Anyways, I removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will behave the same way as `Collections.copy`.

```
public static void copy(List<String> copy_from,List<String> copy_to){
    if (copy_to.size() < copy_from.size()) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("copy_to is too small.");
    }


    ListIterator<String> fromIter = copy_from.listIterator();
    ListIterator<String> toIter = copy_to.listIterator();
    while (fromIter.hasNext()) {
        String next = fromIter.next();
        toIter.next();
        toIter.set(next);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't want to copy elements that are already there. 
Then you can do it this way:

```
public static void copy(List<String> copy_from,List<String> copy_to){
    if(copy_to==null){throw Exception("copy_to can't be null!")}
    //additional checks should be added
    for(String elem : copy_from){
        if(!copy_to.contains(elem)){
            copy_to.add(elem);
        }
    }
}
```